# String [] Array Error

Tags: java

When I used a String [] array, like this:

```
 import java.lang.String.*; 

 import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

 import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class JavaJoe

{

public static void main(String args[]) 

{

String [] day = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

the output of this:

```
if(day[0] == ("Monday"))

{

double cost = 30;

double totalCost = 30 * 1.15; //cost including tax

money = money - totalCost;

System.out.println("It is " + day + " and Joe has to spend " + decimal.format(totalCost) + " on a new pair of shoes. He has " + decimal.format(money) + " left.");

} //if
```

gave me this:

> It is [Ljava.lang.string;@1ea2dfe and Joe has to spend $34.50. He have $165.50 left.

Can you tell me why? Why doesn't it tell me that it's Monday? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `day` is the array; you need to access an entry of the array.

Comment: use if(day[0].equals("Monday")) and then print day[0].

Answer (score 6):

Because you are printing the array itself, which calls the `toString` method of a Java Array. If you check the implementation of this method, you will see it doesn't print the actual values, but instead it will print a unique hash for that object.

> **Object.toString()**
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Now in your code change `day` to `day[0]` and use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` for String comparison. `==` is reference equality.

```
if(day[0].equals("Monday")) 
    System.out.println("It is " + day[0] + " and Joe has to spend " + decimal.format(totalCost) + " on a new pair of shoes. He has " + decimal.format(money) + " left.");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use `equals` to compare strings (i.e. `day[0].equals("Monday")`).

Then, print `day[0]` instead of `day`.

Answer (score 1):

to compare `Strings` you have to use `equals`:

```
if(day[0].equals("Monday"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `day`, wich is an `array`.
Use `day[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing array

It should be  day[0] not day

Answer (score 0):

== operator checks whether the two references point to the same object or not whereas .equals() function will check the string content.

```
String name1 = new String("John");
String name2 = new String("John");
if(name1 == name2 )
{
  System.out.println("Both point to same object");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Both point to different object");      
}
```

output is:

```
Both point to different object
```

whereas for

```
if(name1.equals(name2) )
{
  System.out.println("Both have same content");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Both have different content");      
}
```

output is :

```
Both have same content
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no error, you are printing an array in stdout instead of its elements. this is the default  toString() for objects (printing memory location) print`day[index]`  instead of printing the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `days[0].equals("Monday");`

Secondly ,instead of `System.out.println(day);` use `System.out.println(day[0])`.